# how to save string in HANA which contains percentage sign?

Tags: service, hana, hana-xs

I have an XSJS service where I'm saving some strings in a HANA table like

`oEntity.save(new oEntity(oUploadedData))`

It is working fine but if there is some special character in the string like `%` it fails. Is there any way to escape the percentage sign and save it like that?

Comment: Can you add your xsjs service code here - where you are getting this error??

Comment: use **ALPHANUM** datatype to store special characters as mentioned in [this](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3556486)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. The problem was not the percentage sign but the way i've sent data from the client to the server. 
If you are sending JSON string to the backend which contains percentage sign HANA xsjs gives an internal server error. Instead of just `JSON.stringify(data)` you should use `ecodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))`